# How to run multiple debug instances of a GM:S game

Tags: game-maker

I'm building a client/server application in Game Maker: Studio 1.4 and need to run two instances of the game for testing. Unfortunately, the IDE's run/debug buttons disable themselves after starting the first copy. Is there a way to configure the IDE to permit two instances to run concurrently?

Opening two complete copies of the IDE sort of works, but seems like a great way to break my game by saving things out of sync.

I'm currently exporting the game every time I make a tiny code change and only debugging on the host instance, which is less than ideal.

Is there a way to configure the IDE to allow multiple instances of the game to run via the run/debug buttons?

Comment: Personally, I export every time to test my client-server system. I don't think you can run 2 compiled instances per running gamemaker application.

Comment: Yes, you can. There is a simple command that you can use to run a second runner (the command should be in the compile log). I'll test this out tonight because I could use this too. There is no way to debug both i think because you can only run 1 debug tool, but it should be easy to run a second instance. This saves a lot of time when debugging multiplayer games. Let me figure this out tonight, I'll keep you posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, here's what I have;

When you compile a game from the IDE you'll see a line like this one somewhere in the compile log:

```
C:\Users\You\AppData\Roaming\GameMaker-Studio\Runner.exe -game "C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\gm_ttt_92729\gm_ttt_68071\GAME.win"
```

When you execute that script in a command line (START+R) you'll see the game runs just fine.

In order to automate this, I am using the `working_directory` variable (which returns `C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\gm_ttt_92729\gm_ttt_68071`.

As GM:S does not support executing shell scripts, I have added this free asset to my game:
https://marketplace.yoyogames.com/assets/575/execute-shell

In my game I have added a button which calls this code;
`ExecuteShell('%appdata%\Roaming\GameMaker-Studio\Runner.exe -game ' + working_directory + "ShootMUp.win",0)`

Please note that you'll have to manually edit the `.win` file name.

But, this works and lets me run multiple instances of the same game without exporting it to .exe or build it again.